# R: "formal classes cannot be used without the 'methods' package" error using nrow

Tags: r

I am unable to execute an R programme, as it fails with the error message in the title. I have reduced the programme to a bare minimum that reproduces the error message (R 3.4.4):

```
$ cat countRows.R
countRows <- function(data)
{
        m <- readRDS(data)
        message("Number of rows in m@data: ", nrow(m@data)))
}

# Test function
countRows("~/data/prediction.rds")

$ Rscript countRows.R
Error in nrow(m@data) : 
  formal classes cannot be used without the 'methods' package
Calls: countRows -> message -> paste0 -> nrow
Execution halted
```

`nrow` is part of the `base` package and I can use it in the interactive console without issue (or without important any packages). [A previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553748/ggplot2-error-message-that-i-cant-understand) instructs to "restart the session", but I believe it does not apply to `nrow`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Why not do `nrow(m)`?  Assuming `m` is a data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formal classes (also called S4 classes),
as the error suggests,
require the `methods` package to work properly.
When you use the interactive R console or RStudio,
the package is attached automatically.
However, `Rscript` does *not* do it.
Try adding `library(methods)` to the top of `countRows.R`.

EDIT: this behavior changed in R 3.5.0. The relevant NEWS entry says:

> If --default-packages is not used, then Rscript now checks the environment variable R_SCRIPT_DEFAULT_PACKAGES. If this is set, then it takes precedence over R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES. If default packages are not specified on the command line or by one of these environment variables, then Rscript now uses the same default packages as R. For now, the previous behavior of not including **methods** (package) can be restored by setting the environment variable R_SCRIPT_LEGACY to yes.